# Edit WordPress blog post page - Avada WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I like to customize blog post page in Avada wordpress theme. I have searched all folders inside avada theme, but I can't find out where I could edit blog post `.php` file. Please any one help me out of this problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The code for the blog post will be typically found in **theme/single.php**. You can read more about this file and the overall theme hierarchy on the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Single_Post_.28single.php.29).